# Как отправить письмо на вторую почту администратору сайта СКРЫТНО

Tags: python

как добавить чтобы был дубль письма заказа на вторую почту сайта администратора СКРЫТНО

```
def send_email(request):
                zakaz = OrderItem.objects.filter(number_order=order, number_order__user_order=user_order).select_related('number_order').prefetch_related(
                'number_order__nomer_order',  'number_order__user_order__discount_list_k1').values()
                subject = f"Заказ № {order}"
                message = render_to_string('shop/email.html', {'user': request.user.first_name, 'order': order, 'comment': cd['comment_order'], 'zakaz': zakaz})
                from_email = "gorod@site.ru"
                if subject and message and from_email:
                    try:
                        msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, [request.user.email])
                        msg.attach_alternative(message, "text/html")
                        msg.send()
                    except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse("Invalid header found.")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/created/")
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Make sure all fields are entered and valid.")            
            send_email(request)
```

Comment: создайте список почт получателей и через for отправьте

Comment: msg['Bcc'] скрытую копию для  EmailMultiAlternatives

Comment: https://djangodoc.ru/3.2/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage ответ нашел тут

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому -нибудь пригодится - отправка на основную почту и скрытая копия на другую почту

```
def send_email(request):
               zakaz = OrderItem.objects.filter(number_order=order, number_order__user_order=user_order).select_related('number_order').prefetch_related(
               'number_order__nomer_order',  'number_order__user_order__discount_list_k1').values()
               subject = f"Заказ № {order}"
               message = render_to_string('shop/email.html', {'user': request.user.first_name, 'order': order, 'comment': cd['comment_order'], 'zakaz': zakaz})
               from_email = "gorod@site.ru"
               bcc = 'sktyto@site.ru'
               if subject and message and from_email:
                   try:
                       msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, message, from_email, [request.user.email], [bcc])
                       msg.attach_alternative(message, "text/html")
                       msg.send()
                   except BadHeaderError:
                       return HttpResponse("Invalid header found.")
                   return HttpResponseRedirect("/created/")
               else:
                   return HttpResponse("Make sure all fields are entered and valid.")
           send_email(request)
           return render(request,
                     'created.html',
                     {'order': order})
   else:
       return redirect('order_create')
```